# Is there any faster way to truncate column in Unix

Tags: unix

I want to truncate 4th column of TSV file to given length in Unix. File has records in few millions and is of size 8GB.

I am trying this but it seems to be kind of slow.

```
awk -F"\t" '{s=substr($4,0,256); print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"s"\t"$5"\t"$6"\t"$7}' file > newFile
```

Is there any faster alternatives for same?

Thanks

Comment: How fast is it now?  How fast do you want it?  You can't talk meaningfully about performance without numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command could be written a little more nicely (assuming you are re-building the record), which may give some performance increases:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" } { $4 = substr($4,0,256) }' file > newFile
```

If you have access to a multi-core machine (which you probably do), you can use [GNU parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/). You may want to vary the number of cores you use (I've set 4 here) and the block size that's fed to `awk` (I've set this to two megabytes)...

```
< file parallel -j 4 --pipe --block 2M -q awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" } { $4 = substr($4,0,2) }' > newFile
```

---

---

Here's some testing I did on my system using a 2.7G file with 100 million lines and a block size of 2M:

```
time awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" } { $4 = substr($4,0,2) }' file >/dev/null
```

Results:

```
real    1m59.313s
user    1m57.120s
sys     0m2.190s
```

With one core:

```
time < file parallel -j 1 --pipe --block 2M -q awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" } { $4 = substr($4,0,2) }' >/dev/null
```

Results:

```
real    2m28.270s
user    4m3.070s
sys     0m41.560s
```

With four cores:

```
time < file parallel -j 4 --pipe --block 2M -q awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" } { $4 = substr($4,0,2) }' >/dev/null
```

Results:

```
real    0m54.329s
user    2m41.550s
sys     0m31.460s
```

With twelve cores:

```
time < file parallel -j 12 --pipe --block 2M -q awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" } { $4 = substr($4,0,2) }' >/dev/null
```

Results:

```
real    0m36.581s
user    2m24.370s
sys     0m32.230s
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for these efforts in research. I didn't mean to compare performance in seconds of all approaches. I asked this question just to make sure my approach was not super inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

I’ll assume that your file has exactly one space character between fields and no whitespace at the beginning of the line.  If that is wrong, this can be enhanced. 
Otherwise, this should work:

```
sed 's/^\([^ ]* [^ ]* [^ ]* [^ ]\{1,256\}\)[^ ]* /\1 /'
```

I haven’t actually tested it with 256-character-long data (I tested it with `\{1,2\}` and I have no idea how its speed compares to that of `awk`.  BTW, on some versions, you might need to leave off the backslashes from the curly braces and use just `{1,256}`.

Answer (score 2):

If Scott or Steve's solutions are still too slow, it may be time to break out the C.  Run as `./a.out < file > newFile`.  Test on a small file with some long fields first; I am not 100% sure I have the math right.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int
main(void)
{
    int field = 1;
    int character = 0;
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        switch (c)
        {
        case '\n':
            field = 1;
            character = 0;
            break;
        case '\t':
            character = 0;
            field++;
            break;
        default:
            character++;
            break;
        }
        if (field != 4 || character < 256)
            putchar(c);
    }
    if (ferror(stdout) || fflush(stdout) || fclose(stdout))
    {
        perror("write");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```