# parsing using awk

Tags: parsing, awk

how to parse a file based on data from another file using awk.

i made a script:

```
BEGIN{ FS="\t" ; OFS="\t"

while((getline<"headfpkm")>0) {
        ++a
        id[a]=$1
        fpkm[a]=$2
        print id[a],fpkm[a]
        }
lastid=id[a]
print lastid
close("headfpkm")
}

/$lastid/{
        print $2,$3,$5,$7,$8,$14,fpkm[a]
        a--
        lastid=id[a]
}
END{ print "total lines=",FNR,"\n\nfile 1 index: ",a}
```

when i run it :

```
/$ awk -f testawk.awk file2
```

it runs the BEGIN section properly but doesnt give any output.

```
NM_000014       5.04503
NM_000015       0.586677
NM_000016       1.138332278
NM_000017       0.64386
NM_000018       3.61746
NM_000019       2.8793
NM_000020       10.846
NM_000021       0.685098
NM_000022       46388.6
NM_000026       0.257471
NM_000026
total lines=    10

file 1 index:   10
```

Is anything wrong with the searching section??

file 2 looks like this:

```
34      ACADM   NM_000016       9606    hsa-miR-3148    3       80      87      0.003   -0.016  -0.094  0.082   0.112   -0.160  97
34      ACADM   NM_000016       9606    hsa-miR-3163    1       623     629     0.001   -0.022  -0.020  0.065   0.125   -0.01   57
35      ACADS   NM_000017       9606    hsa-miR-3921    3       68      75      0.013   0.192   -0.097  0.031   -0.039  -0.147  82
35      ACADS   NM_000017       9606    hsa-miR-4303    2       67      73      0.012   0.150   -0.052  0.013   -0.039  -0.036  31
35      ACADS   NM_000017       9606    hsa-miR-4653-5p 3       68      75      0.003   0.192   -0.097  0.031   -0.039  -0.157  84
37      ACADVL  NM_000018       9606    hsa-miR-124     2       31      37      0.003   0.023   -0.057  0.012   -0.032  -0.171  76
37      ACADVL  NM_000018       9606    hsa-miR-1827    2       135     141     -0.007  -0.043  -0.058  0.039   -0.069  -0.258  91
37      ACADVL  NM_000018       9606    hsa-miR-2682    2       134     140     0.003   -0.014  -0.058  0.004   -0.047  -0.232  87
37      ACADVL  NM_000018       9606    hsa-miR-449c    2       134     140     -0.035  -0.014  -0.058  0.004   -0.047  -0.270  92
37      ACADVL  NM_000018       9606    hsa-miR-506     2       31      37      -0.016  0.023   -0.057  0.012   -0.032  -0.190  80
```

Comment: +1 But would you be able to add some sample input? In most cases, the use of `getline()` should be [avoided](http://awk.info/?tip/getline). It's likely that there's an easier and more safe way to solve your problem without it.

Comment: i need to read a column from a file. in this test case i am just using first 10 lines of the data. the file is huge. or is there a method to print the file using sed and take each stream as input for awk ?

Comment: I understand that `headfpkm` (and your `while` loop) is producing the output you have described. But it would be helpful if you could include some contents of `file2`. The approach you're using is almost certainly not the way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is going to be a bit of guess, because I'm not 100% sure as to what you're trying to accomplish. The better way to solve your problem, would be to do something like this:

```
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS="\t"
}

FNR==NR {
    c++

    a[$1]=$2
    next
}

$3 in a {
    print $2,$3,$5,$7,$8,$14,a[$3]
}

END {
    printf "total lines=%s\n\nfile 1 index: %s\n", FNR, c
}
```

Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk headfpkm file2
```

Results:

```
ACADM   NM_000016  hsa-miR-3148     80   87   -0.160  1.138332278
ACADM   NM_000016  hsa-miR-3163     623  629  -0.01   1.138332278
ACADS   NM_000017  hsa-miR-3921     68   75   -0.147  0.64386
ACADS   NM_000017  hsa-miR-4303     67   73   -0.036  0.64386
ACADS   NM_000017  hsa-miR-4653-5p  68   75   -0.157  0.64386
ACADVL  NM_000018  hsa-miR-124      31   37   -0.171  3.61746
ACADVL  NM_000018  hsa-miR-1827     135  141  -0.258  3.61746
ACADVL  NM_000018  hsa-miR-2682     134  140  -0.232  3.61746
ACADVL  NM_000018  hsa-miR-449c     134  140  -0.270  3.61746
ACADVL  NM_000018  hsa-miR-506      31   37   -0.190  3.61746
total lines=10

file 1 index: 10
```

Comment: @bharat_iyengar: Yes it does, you can write, for example; `if ($3 ~ /pattern/) { ... }`. Please see the update that I've made above. Are these the results you're looking for?

Comment: yeah it worked. thanks a lot. 

i wish to know whether the statement `if x in y` works same as `/$x/`

Comment: in case if file 1 was huge and i didnt wish to save it in array, then is it possible to run two streams simultaneously ? for e.g.

`sed '' file1 | awk -f script file2`

Comment: I don't think it would and I don't think I've ever tried. IF `$x` is a pattern, then it's simply (for example); `$0 ~ $x`. But usually you want to test if a variable equals another, like: `$0 == $x`.

Comment: The pipe (`|`) symbol is used to pass output from one command to another. If you wish to speed things up for large files, I find a better way is to use [GNU parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) if you have a multi-core machine. For an example, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14225947/is-there-any-faster-way-to-truncate-column-in-unix/14226141#14226141). HTH.

Comment: Another question, Steve: 

can an array be assigned more than 1 dimensions or do i have pass concatenated fields => `a[$1]=$2+"\t"+$3` or `a[$1]=$0`  

_PS:thanks for your patience_

Comment: @bharat_iyengar: No problem, happy to help! You can concatenate array values like, `a[$1]=$2 "\t" $3`, or, `a[$1]=$2 FS $3`for example. A [pseudo-multi-dimensional array](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multi_002ddimensional.html#Multi_002ddimensional) would could look something like: `a[$1,$2]=$3`, for example (see the note about the `SUBSEP` variable). If you have `gawk`, then you can create a [true multi-dimensional array](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Arrays-of-Arrays.html#Arrays-of-Arrays) like: `a[$1][$2]=$3`, for example. HTH!