# AWK: adding a new field from another file

Tags: linux, bash, loops, awk

I have a file that is delimited with a "@".  It has recurring data that can be used to split the file in sections.  In another file I have data that I would like to add as another column to the first file.  The source of the data that is added will be looped through with every instance of the recurring data from the first file.  The files look like this:

File 1

```
Race1@300Yards@6
Race2@300Yards@7
Race3@250Yards@7
Race4@250Yards@7
Race5@250Yards@8
Race6@250Yards@9
Race7@300Yards@10
Race8@300Yards@12
Race1@330Yards@10
Race2@300Yards@10
Race3@300Yards@10
Race4@300Yards@10
Race5@11/2Miles@11
Race6@7Miles@9
Race7@6Miles@8
Race8@51/2Miles@7
Race9@1Mile@8
Race10@51/2Miles@12
Race1@61/2Miles@6
Race2@11/16Miles@9
Race3@1Mile@9
Race4@11/2Miles@6
Race5@11/16Miles@10
Race6@1Mile@10
Race7@11/16Miles@12
Race8@1Mile@12
```

The other file looks like:

File 2

```
London
New York
Dallas
```

The desired results look like:

```
Race1@300Yards@6@London
Race2@300Yards@7@London
Race3@250Yards@7@London
Race4@250Yards@7@London
Race5@250Yards@8@London
Race6@250Yards@9@London
Race7@300Yards@10@London
Race8@300Yards@12@London
Race1@330Yards@10@New York
Race2@300Yards@10@New York
Race3@300Yards@10@New York
Race4@300Yards@10@New York
Race5@11/2Miles@11@New York
Race6@7Miles@9@New York
Race7@6Miles@8@New York
Race8@51/2Miles@7@New York
Race9@1Mile@8@New York
Race10@51/2Miles@12@New York
Race1@61/2Miles@6@Dallas
Race2@11/16Miles@9@Dallas
Race3@1Mile@9@Dallas
Race4@11/2Miles@6@Dallas
Race5@11/16Miles@10@Dallas
Race6@1Mile@10@Dallas
Race7@11/16Miles@12@Dallas
Race8@1Mile@12@Dallas
```

I know that awk can be used to split the race location by "Race1".  I think it starts by something like:

```
awk '/Race1/{x="Race"++i;}{print $5= something relating to file 2}
```

Does anybody know how to parse using awk, or any other Linux commands, for two files using loops and conditions?

Comment: Are the lines "File 1" and "File 2" actually in the files?

Comment: No the lines "File 1" and "File 2" are not actually in the files.

Comment: Ok I changed my answer then.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [parsing using awk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14252303/parsing-using-awk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you save this as a.awk

```
BEGIN {
    FS  = OFS = "@"
    i = 0 
    j = -1
}
NR == FNR {
    a[i++] = $1        
}
NR != FNR {
    if ($1 == "Race1") 
        j++        
    $4 = a[j]
    print       
}
```

and run

```
awk -f a.awk file2 file1
```

You will get your desired results.

Output

```
Race1@300Yards@6@London
Race2@300Yards@7@London
Race3@250Yards@7@London
Race4@250Yards@7@London
Race5@250Yards@8@London
Race6@250Yards@9@London
Race7@300Yards@10@London
Race8@300Yards@12@London
Race1@330Yards@10@New York
Race2@300Yards@10@New York
Race3@300Yards@10@New York
Race4@300Yards@10@New York
Race5@11/2Miles@11@New York
Race6@7Miles@9@New York
Race7@6Miles@8@New York
Race8@51/2Miles@7@New York
Race9@1Mile@8@New York
Race10@51/2Miles@12@New York
Race1@61/2Miles@6@Dallas
Race2@11/16Miles@9@Dallas
Race3@1Mile@9@Dallas
Race4@11/2Miles@6@Dallas
Race5@11/16Miles@10@Dallas
Race6@1Mile@10@Dallas
Race7@11/16Miles@12@Dallas
Race8@1Mile@12@Dallas
```

**Explanation**

We begin by setting the input and output field separators to `@`. We also initialize our variables `i, j` that will be used as array indices.

The first condition checks if we are going through file2 with the `NR == FNR`. During the first block, we associate the index `i` with the first field, which is the city name. Then we increment `i`.

The second condition checks if we are going through file2 with `NR != FNR`. If the first field is equal to `Race1`, then we increment `j` (notice that we initialized `j` to be -1). We set the 4th field to be `a[j]`, and then we print the line.

Comment: Thank you bkmoney.  Your the shizzznit!